# datetimeindex.floor remove HH:MM:SS information

Tags: python, pandas

When I perform `df.index.floor('12H')` on following two datasets, I get different output format.

```
                     dummy
2015-01-04 00:00:00      1
2015-01-04 02:00:00      1
            dummy
2015-01-04      1
2015-01-04      1
                     dummy
2015-01-04 00:00:00      1
2015-01-04 12:00:00      1
2015-01-04 02:00:00      1
2015-01-04 13:00:00      1
2015-01-04 22:00:00      1
                     dummy
2015-01-04 00:00:00      1
2015-01-04 12:00:00      1
2015-01-04 00:00:00      1
2015-01-04 12:00:00      1
2015-01-04 12:00:00      1
```

How do I keep long time format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" for the first dateset, so that I can further merge this table with others.

This is what I would like to have:

```
                     dummy
2015-01-04 00:00:00      1
2015-01-04 02:00:00      1
                     dummy
2015-01-04 00:00:00      1
2015-01-04 00:00:00      1
```

Answer (score 2):

Dont worry, formats are same, only here are `00:00:00` only not displayed in `DatetimeIndex`, check it by convert to `list`.

So because same format next procesing working nice and correctly.

```
print (df)
            dummy
2015-01-04      1
2015-01-04      1

print (df.index.tolist())
[Timestamp('2015-01-04 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2015-01-04 00:00:00')]
```

You can display `00:00:00` by convert to `strings`, but then lost `DatetimeIndex`, so not recommended:

```
df.index = df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

print (df)
                     dummy
2015-01-04 00:00:00      1
2015-01-04 00:00:00      1

print (df.index)
Index(['2015-01-04 00:00:00', '2015-01-04 00:00:00'], dtype='object')

print (df.index.tolist())
['2015-01-04 00:00:00', '2015-01-04 00:00:00']
```